# How to pass a generic function pointer as parameter

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have several functions that having similiar declarations:

```
int foo(int a);
int bar(int a);
int test(int a);
```

And the logics of my message handlers are exactly the same:

```
void HandleFoo(int a) {
    process(a);
    int ret = foo(a);
    if (ret) 
        print(a);
}

void HandleBar(int a) {
    process(a);
    int ret = bar(a);
    if (ret) 
        print(a);
}

void HandleTest(int a) {
    process(a);
    int ret = test(a);
    if (ret) 
        print(a);
}
```

So I am wondering if it is possible to write a general function:

```
void Handle(int a, func_pointer fn) {
    process(a);
    int ret = fn(a);
    if (ret) 
        print(a);
}
```

The `fn` is like a generic function pointer that can accept `foo`, `bar` and `test`

Is this possible?

Btw, currently no C++11 and boost in my project, only using TR1.

Comment: `typedef int (*func_pointer)(int)` should do the trick. Then : `Handle(10, &foo);` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a template

Example (not your code exactly) :

```
int add1(int n) { return n + 1; }
int add2(int n) { return n + 2; }

template<typename Adder>
void AddHandler(int n, Adder adder)
{
    int r = adder(n);
    std::cout << r << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    AddHandler(1, add1);
    AddHandler(3, add2);

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs as expected :

```
2
5
```

You can see it live here http://ideone.com/q3FyI5

Answer (score 2):

Convert the functions to functors, i.e.

```
struct foo
{
    int operator()(int a) {}
};
struct bar
{
    int operator()(int a) {}
};
struct test
{
    int operator()(int a) {}
};
```

then the previous approach works, *with a slight tweak*

```
template <typename Functor>
void Handle(int a)
{
    process(a);
    int ret = Functor()(a); // <- tweak, instantiate functor and then call
    if (ret) 
        print(a);
}
```

You can take this approach or @undu's where you pass the function to call as an argument.

Comment: Thanks. What if I put this in a class? I tried but the compiler says: error: no matching function for call to `'A::Handle(int)'`, candidate is: `template<class FnType> void A::Handle(int)`, template argument deduction/substitution failed

Comment: @undu, I blame not enough coffee... :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Use

```
void Handle(int a, int(*func)(int)) {
  process(a);
  int ret = (*func)(a);
}
```

Use like so:

```
Handle(some_a, &foo);
```

Note: the three functions you posted as example return `void`, I suspected a typo and replaced them with `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef int (*fptr)(int ) ;

void Handle(int a, fptr fn) {
    process(a);
    int ret = fn(a);
    if (ret) 
        print(a);
}

int main()
{
    Handle(3,foo);
    Handle(4,bar);
    Handle(5,test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
void Handle(int a, bool(*fn)(int) ) {
    process(a);
    int ret = fn(a);
    if (ret) 
        print(a);
}
```

Or,

```
typedef bool (*func_pointer)(int);
void Handle(int a, func_pointer fn ) {
    process(a);
    int ret = fn(a);
    if (ret) 
        print(a);
}
```