# C# language doesn't need the concept of delegates?

Tags: java, c#, c++, callback, delegates

***Thank***s for your objectivity, especially where C# is your language of choice. Angry downvoters, I think I've asked a legitimate question here? Otherwise leave a constructive comment, please.

To the question...

- C++ allows passing of (generic) function pointers simply, as follows: [How to pass a generic function pointer as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965057/how-to-pass-a-generic-function-pointer-as-parameter)
- Java uses interfaces for this - also elegant from an OO perspective, we use nothing more than what the basic language already supplies.

However, I have never seen any real advantage to making `delegate` an explicit concept / keyword, as opposed to just managing the concept of callbacks the way that for example C++ or Java do -- by treating function pointers as just another circumstance under *existing* type system. (P.S. yes, C# generics are not the same as C++ generics, while Java has runtime rather than compile-time generics, but you get my drift).

(All hubris and dogma aside) Why did the designers of C# see fit to give a new name to a common, existing programming concept that could have been called a generic function pointer / callback? Could delegates not have been more simply represented in C#, without such a concept?

**DISCLAIMER** I've looked at quite a number of answers on stackoverflow and not one of them has satisfactorily answered why the designers saw fit to include another keyword for something so fundamental as callback handling.

Comment: If you don't like it, you can always use Func<T> etc

Comment: Well, for starters, a delegate can reference multiple functions (see multicast delegates). So calling it a function pointer would be inaccurate

Comment: C# doesn't have templates, so you can't use the C++ approach (anything that overloads the `()` operator goes).

Comment: @Kookiz Interesting. And yet necessary? Do you add a new language concept just because you don't want to loop through your callback functions (e.g. Java observer pattern)? I appreciate that it _is so_; I just wonder again why they went down this whole road.

Comment: i think the point is that delegates are typesafe: "Delegates are like C++ function pointers but are type safe." - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx

Comment: Let's make that 'somewhat typesafe'

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer Note that the `delegate` keyword is a synctactic sugar of C#. In IL code (so in ".NET"), `delegate`s are simply subclasses of `MulticastDelegate` (that is a subclass of `Delegate`) with an `Invoke()` method with the "right" signature, so they are similar to Java "missing" "delegates" (that are an interface with a single method). The `Invoke()` method is then handled by the CLR

Comment: @xanatos Still they involve quite a bit of CLR magic you wouldn't need if they you used single method interfaces, like java.

Comment: Delegates are actually classes that extend `System.MulticastDelegate`, and additionally provide `BeginInvoke()`, `EndInvoke()` and `Invoke()` methods. So they are far more than simple function pointers.

Comment: The interface variant would be difficult to implement without incurring the cost of *two* indirect calls, instead of just *one*.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I don't see the difference... there is an object and there is a vtable... With interfaces the vtable is implicit/hidden in the interface/implementation class, with delegates the vtable is a local field of the delegate.

Comment: I'll add that Java 8 has tried to copy C# `delegate`s, without admitting they are a good idea: [functional interfaces](http://www.journaldev.com/2763/java-8-lambda-expressions-and-functional-interfaces-example-tutorial)

Comment: BeginInvoke()/EndInvoke() are tricky ones, they don't exist until we use them, runtime generates them at first usage. Also, they take care of handling the ExecutionContext, so ambient variables, security related stuff will travel with the call. Delegates do so many things and used so frequently in .NET code, that I think it is way more than a syntactic sugar. We can say that 'for' loop is a syntactic sugar, and to be honest I would rather implement a for loop by hand using 'if' and 'goto' than all the things delegates provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ had "official" (non-Boost) "full" delegates from C++11 (`std::function`)... Before that, getting a pointer to a member function was always a little hackish... So I wouldn't consider C++ to be a good comparison :-) And C++ can overload the round parenthesis, so it is more easy to "hide" the hacks that need to be done and give to the programmer a "simple" way of using the `std::function`.

Now... Java... To "correct" (but let's say it wasn't an omission, but a calculated decision, so they didn't have anything to correct) the missing delegate concept they first had to introduce anonymous classes in Java 1.1 and then in Java 8 they introduced functional interfaces (as a non-Java programmer, I consider the last thing to be a little hackish... meta-describing that an interface has a single method and then enforcing it at compile time... I don't like it very much...). This because otherwise the boilerplate code that is needed is quite much...

Let's start simple... The `IComparer<>` interface... It is an interface with a single method, so it is very similar to a delegate...

a simple implementation:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<int>
{
    public int Compare(int x, int y)
    {
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

There is a boilerplate row here, the first one (`public class MyComparer : IComparer<int>`). By introducing the C# `delegate` you already gained one row for each use of a delegate... But wait! Let's say that your "delegate" needs a reference to the class that "contains" it...

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<int>
{
    public MyClass Target;

    public int Compare(int x, int y)
    {
        return Target.Ascending ? x.CompareTo(y) : y.CompareTo(x);
    }
}
```

And now this class needs to be a nested class of `MyClass`. Note that I don't have anything against nested classes...

We have added a new line (`public MyClass Target`)... But this code is normally wrong to write... You shouldn't have public non-readonly fields. You could use an auto-property `public MyClass Target { get; set; }` but that too is synctactic sugar introduced in C# 3.0... without them the boilerplate code would grow... And I would prefer to have a `private readonly MyClass Target`.. But then I would have to add four lines for the constructor... How many lines do you want me to write for a delegate? :-)

And still C#/.NET delegates give more flexibility: the function you use can have any name, so you can have multiple of them in the same class... The `MyComparer` could have been implemented as two methods:

```
public int CompareAscending(int x, int y) {}
```

and

```
public int CompareDescending(int x, int y) {}
```

without adding too much code, or splitting everything in multiple (nested) classes.

Comment: I don't think it's conclusive (yet?), but this is great food for thought (as well as your comments). I am digesting.

Comment: Just to add, I do agree about the Java / interface thing in retrospect. I think that it's unfortunate that Java  & C# didn't treat functions as first class citizens, the way C and the ECMA languages do.

Answer (score 3):

Delegates are more than a simple callback. First, it works both for static methods and instance methods and the caller doesn't have to take care of the differences. Second, delegate is not a single method pointer. It can be a "pointer chain", so the caller can call many callbacks with a single call - and again, the caller doesn't have to bother wheter it is a single or multiple call.
Yes, one can implement the same mechanism from scratch - but one can build everything using machine code - what need for high level languages.

Comment: Thanks Viktor. The thing is, it still seems like syntactic sugar, and most language designers don't take lightly the impacts of adding complexity to a language. Looping through callbacks is trivial and beneath the hood (at IL level), the system still has to loop through function pointers -- you cannot call multiple functions at once, obviously.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer Consider that the delegates are the base for the `event`s... (that are first level things in .NET)... They could have moved the code from delegates to events, but it wouldn't have changed much... And events are all-over-the-place in Winforms (that was the first UI of .NET)

Comment: @xanatos Right, now _that_ is relevant. Though as you say I do wonder why it wasn't done as part of `event`s. Let's see if there are further comments on this.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer I'll add that the fact that all the delegates are `MulticastDelegate` and the `Delegate` (single) isn't used anywhere, while a `MulticastDelegate` has sense only for an `event` (I haven't ever added together delegates outside an `event`... it seems to be something quite rare) seems to show this relationship was forefront in the head of the creators of .NET/C#

Comment: @xanatos Do we know why events are first class / fundamental concepts in C#? Since this may be at the root of this design decision.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer By looking at the generated IL code, http://goo.gl/jRCWrC, both `properties` and `event`s are thin "containers" for methods (`get`/`set` and `add`/`remove`)... They probably exist at the .NET level to permit some cataloging of methods. Especially for properties, it is easier if you can do `typeof(MyType).GetProperties()` than if you have to do `typeof(MyType).GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("get_")`. They could "not exist" and they could be "simulated" at the C# level with some naming conventions, like it is done for `operator`s. It would be nearly the same.

Comment: @xanatos I reckon this is indeed the root: `event`s were under the hood, so `delegate`s had to be too for .NET platform code to make sense. Whether the reason for `event`s being there was classification, reflection, performance or something else, it had a slew of knock-on effects leading us to where we are today. It would be great to have someone involved in early .NET development confirm or deny this causality. If you could add your comments from below this answer to yours, I will accept yours, as without confirmed history, guesses are the best we have.