# Passing function as reference in template?

Tags: c++, templates

Recently I've came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17965239/183612).
I've noticed that a variation of this answer to:

```
template<typename Adder>
void AddHandler(int n, Adder& adder)
{
    int r = adder(n);
    std::cout << r << std::endl;
}
```

also works. Does it matter how a function is passed? Is one way preferred over the other? How about performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `AddHandler` is called with a function `f` that takes an `int` and returns an `int`

```
int f(int i) { return i; }
```

then the template taking a reference

```
template<typename Adder>
void AddHandler(int n, Adder& adder);  // #1
```

will deduce `Adder` to be a function object type, specifically `int(int)`.

However, the overload taking a value

```
template<typename Adder>
void AddHandler(int n, Adder adder);  // #2
```

will deduce `Adder` to be a function pointer, i.e. `int (*)(int)`.

There won't be any performance differences between `#1` and `#2`, but there are some differences in usage.

In `#1`, `adder` is a reference, so it can't be assigned a different function. You can do this with `#2`. Assuming a function `int g(int);`

```
adder = g; // error with #1
           // ok with #2
```

Also, you can't pass a temporary to `#1`, but you can to `#2`.

```
AddHandler(42, [](int i) { return i; }); // error with #1
                                         // ok with #2
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy answer! Btw. in general, do I loose any potential compilator optimizations when I pass a function instead of calling it directly, say in non-template scenario? I.e. is the cost of passing a function the only performance cost?

Comment: @Ranza No, just passing a function pointer shouldn't be any different than calling the function directly. But in general, you should always profile your code to see if something like that is actually affecting your performance.

Comment: You can lose some potential for optimization if the compiler doesn't know what function will be called at compile time.  A call to an unknown function can't be inlined, for example, and a dynamic call may be a bit harder on the CPU's branch prediction.  These downsides are only likely to make a difference in very tight loops and such though.  In most generic business logic code the effect will likely be minor to negligible.

Comment: @MilesBudnek thanks. That's what I've been expecting.

Answer (score 1):

There is one other consideration that is often overlooked, and that is if the callable is a class with separate overloads for lvalue and rvalue references of the function object itself.

Then the value category of the function object provided can also affect what happens.  In those (admittedly rare) cases where people do need to have different behaviors for function objects, it's important to invoke it properly to keep the behavior as intended.

Given the original function and AddHandlers, with one change to the one taking a reference... it now takes a reference to a const object, allowing binding the reference to rvalues (but it loses infomration on its value category.  Once bound to a non-modifiable lvalue reference, we do not know if it was actually an rvalue or lvalue that bound):

```
int add1(int n) { return n+1; }

template<typename Adder>
void AddHandler1(int n, Adder adder) {
    int r = adder(n);
    std::cout << r << std::endl;
}

template<typename Adder>
void AddHandler2(int n, Adder const & adder) // << ADDED const
{
    int r = adder(n);
    std::cout << r << std::endl;
}
```

Let's add one more overload that does perfect forwarding to maintain the value category of the callable:

```
template<typename Adder>
void AddHandler3(int n, Adder&& adder)     //<<<< NOTE: &&
{
    int r = std::forward<Adder>(adder)(n); //<<<< NOTE: std::forward
    std::cout << r << std::endl;
}

// Adds 1 just like add1() does when called on an lvalue,
// but adds 2 when called on an rvalue instance of this class
class MyAdder {
public:
    int operator()(int arg) const & {
       return arg + 1;
    }

    int operator()(int arg) const && {
       return arg + 2;
    }
};
```

Now, if we invoke all three of them in groups:

```
MyAdder myAddrObj;

// This version make a copy, so value category is lost
AddHandler1(0, add1);        // = 1   (function pointer)
AddHandler1(0, myAddrObj);   // = 1   (lvalue ref)
AddHandler1(0, MyAdder{});   // = 1   (converts to lvalue)

// this takes a ref to const, and value category is lost also
AddHandler2(10, add1);       // = 11  (function pointer)  
AddHandler2(10, myAddrObj);  // = 11  (lvalue ref)
AddHandler2(10, MyAdder{});  // = 11  (converts to const& )

// takes the callable as a forwarding-reference, 
// maintains value category.  Notice the result changes for 
// the rvalue invocation.
AddHandler3(100, add1);      // = 101   (function pointer)
AddHandler3(100, myAddrObj); // = 101   (lvalue ref)
AddHandler3(100, MyAdder{}); // = 102!! (rvalue ref)
```

See it live https://godbolt.org/z/nhneoaj54

And a final, important thing to remember: while it's a good idea to take callables through forwarding references, only do so if you will invoke it *once*, because once it has forwarded it must be treated as a moved object and you can't use it again.  So do *not* do this for functions that perform loops, etc., since you would need to invoke the function multiple times, but cannot once it has been moved.